# Trying not to overwrite a file in C?

Tags: c, file, fopen

Hi I'm trying not to overwrite a file in C using fopen(file, "w");

My question is the file already exists as a 10 MB file but when I used the fopen the file ends up becoming 1KB. I want to write something to the file but I want it to stay the same size as well. How would I accomplish this? I saw that the "a+" appends things to the end of the file but what if I want to write something to the beginning of the file without expanding the size? It's just an empty file

Alternatively, is there a way to create a file in C with a certain size (such as 10MB)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. By opening it with `r+` you open it for 'reading and writing' (while `w` opens it for writing freshly).

Regarding your other question: Open a file with `w` and write 1000 1024 byte blocks to the file like this:

```
FILE *fp = fopen("file", "wb");
if(fp) {
    int i = 0;
    char Buf[1024];
    for(; i < 1000; ++i)
        fwrite(Buf, 1, 1024, fp);
    fclose(fp);
}
```

Just once more the fopen flags for you:

`r` -> Opens file for reading. (File remains unchanged)
`w` -> Opens file for writing. (File gets erased)
`a` -> Opens file for appending. (File remains unchanged, file pointer gets moved to end)

Aside from these three main types, you can add a few more additional options:
`b`  -> Opens the file as binary, ignoring formatting characters like \n
`t`  -> Opens the file as text, specifically parsing \n as \r\n under Windows.

Comment: That's better.Anyways,edit the question please into a better format.Change the caption of the question too.I am lazy and sleepy.

Answer (score 2):

Open the file, then use [`fseek`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fseek) to set your position to the beginning of your file.

**Edit**: use `r+` mode when opening. From `man fopen`:

```
r+     Open for reading and writing.  The stream is positioned at
       the beginning of the file.
```

Comment: He wants to keep the size of the file the same.

Answer (score 1):

**a way to create a file in C with a certain size (such as 10MB)?*

like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){
    const char *TenMBfile = "TenMB";
    FILE *fp;
    fp=fopen(TenMBfile, "w");
    fseek(fp, 10*1024*1024-1,SEEK_SET);
    fputc(0, fp);
    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Hye! I worked on a project for adding text or 'blog' post on my web page and I found a pretty cool way to do it.
For this, I'll use a HTML file and my program.
HTML FILE:

```html
<html>
<body>
<p> Hey this is the asssdsadasdsadas paragraph</p><br>
<p> Hey this is the asssdsadasdsadas paragraph</p><br>

</body>
</html>
```

C FILE:

```
printf("Please enter the number of bytes to write from in %s .\n", argv[0]);
    int offset;
    scanf("%d", &offset);
    fseek(fp, -offset, SEEK_END);
    strcat(argv[1], "<br>\n\n");
    fprintf(fp, "%s", argv[1]);
    fprintf(fp, "</body>\n</html>\n");
```

HTML explanation:

1. I start with one line defined
2. I put a blank line which I am going to write there.
3. Then I got all my ending tags.

C explanation:

1. I ask how many bytes I want to seek from the ending of the file wich is 17 in this case(to write to the blank line).
2. I get the number with scanf()
3. Then I seek in the file at minus x bytes because normally it's going to add bytes and we specify the whence.
4. Then for the purpose, here I add a break tag and also 2 newline to continue the cycle.
5. Then I write my wanted text.
6. Last, I add my 2 last tags, because when I write my text, it overwrites all after it. So after, the cursor is positioned after the last newline and I can write the ending tags.

So... This is how you can do it.